# SMTP service to send email on my web application

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

I've been using gmail's SMTP server to send email (notifications, password reminder, etc) in my web application.  However, i'm getting to the point where i'm reaching the limit of 500 sent emails per day using gmail's SMTP.

Is there any SMTP service's that I can use instead?  A friend told me about sendgrid.com, but that's the only one i've heard of.

Comment: This would probably be better off on serverfault, since it's asking about services/servers, not how to write SMTP code.

Comment: Doesn't your web hosting package come with a SMTP server of its own?

Answer (score 2):

Besides [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) which you mentioned, there is also [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) for transaction emails and [Newsberry](http://newsberry.com/) for email marketing

Answer (score 2):

I recently found http://www.mandrill.com which seems to be transaction e-mail service from MailChimp. It allows to send e-mails thru SMTP and API. It also provide many other functions like delivery, open tracking, templates ans so on. Its free for up to 12000 e-mails per month.

Answer (score 1):

[JangoSMTP](http://www.jangosmtp.com/) is another option. You can send via SMTP or API and it comes with open tracking, click tracking, a Google Analytics integration, and log reporting.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use your local mta on your server as pekka said. something like /usr/sbin/sendmail on unix or the SMTP Service in IIS on win

Comment: the SMTP service on my shared server is also restricted to about 250 emails sent per day...

Comment: ahh that sux! since its shared you probably cant install an alternate smtp server, maybe theres another host at your company you can route through? there's always smtp.com which is fairly handy in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

[Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) and [Deliver](http://deliverhq.com) are probably the best tools for this. Of course another possibility is to install an email server like Postfix on your web server, which can handle a large number of emails without any cost, though won't have the delivery reliability or tracking offered by a paid service.